# Using a Timer to perform AsyncTask periodically

Tags: android, timer, background, android-asynctask

I'm using a `Timer` to download some data with an `AsyncTask` periodically (once in a minute) while app is in foreground.

When app moves to background I read that the timer can be "killed" if there are any other memory-hogging applications running on your device.

1. So if I go back to my app I need to restart the timer, but only if it has been killed. Will the timer be `null` if it's killed? How can I detect this?
2. Another way would be to stop the timer when app goes to background and then start the timer when app goes to foreground. Are there any ways to detect when app moves to/from background from/to foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Override `onRestart` method when app is being restarted or in foreground like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //Cancel your timer and then restart with your code.
        timer.cancel()
        //start timer with your existing code.
    }
```